# Java entity classes from a proprietary database?

Tags: java, json, entity-framework, netbeans

Friends i have one database which maintain schema files in JSON format but it doesn't support JDBC connectivity so i can't use existing netbeans feature "entity class from database"
this proprietary database gives me following table schema

```
{
"uid":{
  "auto-define":"none",
  "name":"uid",
  "index":"unique",
  "type":{
     "length":-1,
     "type":"STRING"
  }
},
"createdAt":{
  "auto-define":"none",
  "name":"createdAt",
  "index":"none",
  "type":{
     "type":"LONG"
  }
},
"lastLogin":{
  "auto-define":"none",
  "name":"lastLogin",
  "index":"none",
  "type":{
     "type":"LONG"
  }
},
"password":{
  "auto-define":"none",
  "name":"password",
  "index":"none",
  "type":{
     "length":-1,
     "type":"STRING"
  }
},
"blocked":{
  "auto-define":"none",
  "name":"blocked",
  "index":"none",
  "type":{
     "type":"BOOLEAN"
  }
},
"replication-type":"distributed",
"replication-factor":1,
"email":{
  "auto-define":"none",
  "name":"email",
  "index":"btree",
  "type":{
     "length":-1,
     "type":"STRING"
  }
},
"primary":"uid",
"network":{
  "auto-define":"none",
  "name":"network",
  "index":"none",
  "type":{
     "length":-1,
     "type":"STRING"
  }
 }
}
```

so from above schema (JSON) i want the entity class like

```
@Entity
public class User extends CloudStorage {
    @Primary
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

please help me, i want to develop a NetBeans plugin which will get all the table schema (JSON) and gives the ability to select the table and generate entity classes.

Comment: What is the question here?  (Hint: "please help me" ... do what?)

Comment: I want to develop a NetBeans plugin same as "Entity class from database" where you can select datasource and all the table list will get displayed on one dailog box so, i can select tables and generate Entity classes (POJO) for those tables.

Comment: And what is your question?  It would probably take a whole book to explain everything involved in addressing your requirements.  (And, no, I don't know of a book that would explain it.  I'm saying that we can't write a book-sized answer for you.)

Comment: sorry actually i'm new here on stackoverflow.
I just want a utility using that i could convert my table (JSON) schema to java entity classes. How i can generate POJO by giving that JSON string as input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want a utility using that i could convert my table (JSON) schema to java entity classes. How i can generate POJO by giving that JSON string as input ?

I would be surprised if there is an off-the-shelf solution that does *exactly* what you want.  (Certainly not one that takes some unnamed / unspecified proprietary database JSON as input ...)

Here is one idea for to implement a utility yourself.  (There are probably others ... but I will leave the task of looking for them to someone else.)

The ["jsonschema2pojo"](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo) tool will generate Java POJO source code from a JSON schema.  However, your input is not a valid JSON schema. So figure out a mapping from your database JSON to regular JSON schema (i.e. one based on http://json-schema.org) and then:

1. Write a converter that converts your JSON to a JSON schema.
2. Use jsonschema2pojo (embedded) to read the JSON schema and generate the POJO source code.

Indeed, you could possible fold the two steps into one by modifying jsonschema2pojo to do the schema to schema conversion on the fly.